# Merge Module Project Help - Visual Studio 2005

Tags: visual-studio-2005, deployment-project

I am currently making changes to my company's enterprise library and I am looking into creating a deployment project that will allows developer to set up the library through the MSI installer or some type of set up executable.

I was looking into using a Merge Module project to accomplish this task.  A basic google search did not produce any helpful resources for using Merge Module Product.

Do anyone know of useful resource/tutorial on creating Merge Module projects or do they have a better suggestion for accomplishing this task?

**UPDATE**

I was able to build my Merge Module project with the appropriate references to all the need assemblies.  It produced a .MSM file.  What is the next step to actually run and test it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An MSM cannot be run or tested *per se*. However, you can embed it into an MSI and then simply try to install the MSI using the standard tools (i.e. either manually right-clicking on the MSI and selecting **Install** or **Uninstall**, do so using Visual Studio, or by executing the corresponding `msiexec.exe` commands).

To embed an MSM into an MSI, the easiest way is to create a setup project in Visual Studio and add the **Merge Module** from the merge module project you have just created in your solution. This will automatically reference the MSM file and include it into the MSI.

Comment: Another developer helped me with setting up a Visual Studio project and referencing the MSM file in the project and adding project output to the setup project.

Comment: Great! So now you have a solution with two setup projects in it: an MSM project and an MSI project referencing the MSM. Did you achieve what you were trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same lack of documentation when I built my only merge module using Visual Studio 2005. I had some experience with the MSI Setup projects, and I simply applied the information I had for the MSI Setup projects to the MSM.

In Visual Studio 2005 (or 2008), both MSI and MSM projects are handled in a very similar manner. Add files to the project (either explicitly or through a reference to another project found in the same solution), then use the right-click on the project to :

1. View the file system.
2. View the registry settings.
3. View the file types associations.
4. View the custom actions.

Custom actions can be implemented in a .NET assembly, for instance, by subclassing the `Installer` class. Here is an example which would, for instance, install or uninstall a printer when the MSM/MSI gets installed or uninstalled:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration.Install;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Epsitec.PostScriptPrinterInstaller
{
    [RunInstaller (true)]
    public partial class PrinterInstaller : Installer
    {
        public PrinterInstaller()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent ();
        }
        public override void Install(System.Collections.IDictionary stateSaver)
        {
            base.Install (stateSaver);
            string sysroot = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable ("SystemRoot");
            string infpath = @"""" + System.IO.Path.Combine (sysroot, @"inf\ntprint.inf") + @"""";
            ProcessStartInfo info;
            Process process;

            info = new ProcessStartInfo ("rundll32.exe",
                       @"printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /if /b ""PostScript"" /m ""MS Publisher Color Printer"" /f "+infpath+@" /r ""FILE:""");

            process = Process.Start (info);
            process.WaitForExit ();
        }

        public override void Uninstall(System.Collections.IDictionary savedState)
        {
            base.Uninstall (savedState);
            ProcessStartInfo info;
            info = new ProcessStartInfo ("rundll32.exe",
                       @"printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /dl /n ""PostScript""");
            Process process = Process.Start (info);
            process.WaitForExit ();

            info = new ProcessStartInfo ("rundll32.exe",
                       @"printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /dd /m ""MS Publisher Color Printer""");
            process = Process.Start (info);
            process.WaitForExit ();
        }
    }
}
```

I hope that with this information, you will be able to do some progress.

Comment: Feel free to up vote the replies you find useful on this site, or accept one of the answers; this is both positive for the people who answered and for the people who'll be interested in the same topic as you and who will know: aha there were good answers there!